# Weak wifi signals or sometimes no signals in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless

so I am getting very weak wifi signals on ubuntu 20.04. I have a dual boot with windows 10 and the wifi connections give proper signals on windows but not on ubuntu. Even sitting directly in front of the router gives 2 points of signals at maximum. It completely stops detecting wifi if the laptop moves two to three feet away from the router. While I am getting full signal strength on windows, I am getting no signals in ubuntu.

the output of `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Infinity"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:0E:F4:C0:85:C4   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=20/70  Signal level=-90 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:43   Missed beacon:0

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

output of `lshw -C network`

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 31
       serial: a8:6b:ad:62:12:df
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.13.2-051302-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.10.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:134 memory:d1000000-d11fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 98:40:bb:35:3c:07
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.2-051302-generic firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d1204000-d1204fff memory:d1200000-d1203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 9a:73:25:55:d7:c4
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.13.2-051302-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.191.34 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I checked software and updates as well to see if there was an update for the driver but there wasn't.

I tried to downgrade to the latest generic kernel version as well.

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT:

Posting the speedtest below with wifi connected and with phone's USB tethering with the same wifi connection

WITH LAPTOP WIFI CONNECTED:

```
Ping: 99.974 ms
Download: 0.92 Mbit/s
Upload: 0.40 Mbit/s
```

WITH USB TETHERING TO THE SAME WIFI CONNECTION:

```
Ping: 43.327 ms
Download: 4.28 Mbit/s
Upload: 1.48 Mbit/s
```

Comment: Could you make a speed test? Linux usually measures more accurate than windows. At the end the bits received in a certain time is all what counts..

Comment: @Nmath No because Im literally four feet away from the router and ubuntu cannot see any wifi networks.

Comment: @kanehekili the problem is that it stops detecting wifi even if I move 3 to four feet away from the router

Comment: @kanehekili I added the speedtests too. It performs significantly slower on wifi than when connected to a mobile USB tethering with same wifi cnnection.

Comment: @AnxiousConcert did you find any solution, as i m also facing the same issue. With WIFI it does not work but with USB tethering it is working.